# How to install mongodb in windows 8.1 operating system?

Tags: mongodb

I am using windows 8.1 os. I want to install mongodb in my system. How to install mongodb in windows 8.1 os?

I tried the following link. But I couldn't install mongodb properly.

[mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Comment: run the cmd as adminstrative other cmd closes every time when you launch mongod service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow the instructions given in the following link. This may help you to install mongodb in your windows system.'

[mongodb installation](http://soloso.blogspot.in/2014/02/mongodb-m101p-windows-81-64bit.html)

You can download it from [download mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads)